# Why have my google chrome extensions all been put into a tiny dropdown?

Tags: google-chrome, extension

On my windows PC in my office, my chrome extensions are all along the toolbar as they always have been, however on my ubuntu machine at home they are now in a dropdown next to the spanner icon. It's a bit annoying as I can't see when I have new mail, tweets etc.

Chrome version 7.0.517.44

If anyone knows how to resolve this it would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Drew

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can show all your extensions:

- Take your mouse to the right end url bar.
- Arrow will turn double-headed.
- Drag it to the left.
- You may drag extensions as you wish too

Comment: OMG, thanks a lot!! I dunno how that happened! Nice one. I see, I can hide as many as I want!

Comment: you may drag extensions as you wish too

Comment: I don't know why I did not understand this answer, so I am going to rephrase it for people as stupid as me...

Comment: You can put your mouse on the right-hand side of the Location Bar (in between the yellow bookmarking star and the extensions/dropdown).  Then you can drag the URL bar to make ir shorter or longer, and make more or less room for the extensions icons.

Answer (score 1):

Put your mouse inside the red "circle" indicated in the image below, and then click-and-drag left or right.

[image: Red ellipse indicates the target.]

Your cursor should turn into a `<=||=>` icon when you are there.

*It might have been better if the UI designers had faded a drag widget into view when you put your pointer there.  Although I still wouldn't have found it without help...  :P*

*They could also have put a widget there "permanently", and then made it disappear once the user has played with it a few times.*

Answer (score 0):

I hope this makes things a little more clear:

[image: Click and hold then drag to the left]

Click and hold then drag to the left

[image]

Extension icons should be visible